# PHP Benchmarking - checking for unset variables or warnings off

Tags: php, benchmarking, error-reporting, variable-assignment

Does anyone know of the advantages disadvantages e.g. speed for checking to see if a variable is set rather than simply turning off warnings?

below is very bad example but illustrates what I mean:

```
#Does a check for the variable - error reporting on (Display no warnings)
$i = (!isset($i)) ? $i + 5 : 5;

#error reporting off (Display no warnings)
$i = $i + 5;
```

Thanks in advance for any thoughts!

Comment: You should _always_ develop with `error_reporting` enabled (and preferred with `E_ALL | E_STRICT`). With this in mind your question feels senseless: Your second example must be seen as "slightly buggy".

Comment: You should develop with errors on and turn them off for production. Most of the time things it catches (like declaring variables) will not only save you headaches but may actually speed up your programs. All-in-all, its really going to be microseconds, so I would worry more about good code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This boils down to a fundamental issue: is it more important for your application to run correctly, or to run quickly?

If you simply ignore warnings, logical errors may be overlooked. Your program may execute quickly, but the fastest faulty application has less value than the slowest functional one.

Comment: plus I'd wager that unless the faster approach is implemented on a very large scale you will never see the performance benefit, and you'll have rough code forever. Try to think of the poor guy who inherits your project, enables warnings, and thinks that he's done something wrong.